# ThreadPool context manager problem with appy_async method?

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I am having a problem with ThreadPool when used as context manager.  When I use the apply_async method and try to get results with get() method - it just hangs.

The code provided has the ThreadPool as a context manager.  This always hangs at bottom when trying to get the results.
I have commented the code that does work (option #2) where I manually create and close the pool.

Any ideas as to why it hangs?

```
import threading
import time
import random
import os
import logging
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool


glock = threading.Lock()

def run(pause_time, lock=glock):
    thread_name = threading.currentThread().name
    logging.info(f'attempting lock for thread: {thread_name}')
    with lock:
        logging.info(f'got lock for thread: {thread_name}')
        logging.info(f'pausing {pause_time} seconds for {thread_name}')
        time.sleep(pause_time)

    logging.info(f'released lock for thread: {thread_name}')

    return 'abc'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    format = "%(asctime)s: %(message)s"
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format=format)

    jobs = []
    job = None
    num_threads = os.cpu_count()

    """Optin #1 does not work, the jobs.get() will hang!"""
    with ThreadPool(num_threads) as pool:
        for i in range(1):
            pause_time = random.randint(1,5)
            jobs.append(pool.apply_async(run, args=(pause_time,glock)))

    """Option #2 works fine!  Will need to uncomment"""
    # pool = ThreadPool(num_threads)
    # for i in range(2):
    #     pause_time = random.randint(1,5)
    #     jobs.append(pool.apply_async(run, args=(pause_time,glock)))
    # pool.close()


    pool.join()
    for job in jobs:
        job.get()
    
    logging.info('finished')
```

Comment: Where do you set `job` to something that supports `.get()`?

Comment: I updated the code a bit.  Removed some lines that might cause confusion.  I also had a for loop that used 'res' for each job in jobs array (which I changed to 'job').  It is the job.get() that hangs.